# What does it mean when a CVE is termed as 'retired'?

Tags: security

On https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam, it says that CVEs are fixed and then retired. What is the difference between fixed and retired? When is a CVE called retired?

Comment: -1: You seem to be misquoting the page, and then asking a question about the incorrect quote.

Comment: I apologize for the misquote. Thank you for answering the question's intent in detail.

Answer (score 1):

It actually says:

> As issues are fixed the CVEs are updated and retired.

*Fixed* means that the vulnerability has been closed (usually by a patch), and the the patched package has been uploaded to the Ubuntu repositories.

*Updated* means that the CVE/USN record on the tracker at https://security.ubuntu.com is updated to reflect the final disposition.

*Retired* means that the CVE is considered resolved, no further work will be done on it. There are several possible resolutions to a CVE: Fixed, Won't Fix, Not Applicable, etc.

If a bug is discovered in a CVE patch, the CVE is not reopened. A new bug report and/or CVE is opened.